# Is there an app that lets you swap all open windows between monitors?

Tags: macos, display

I use a separate monitor for each of my sitting and standing desks. I would like to know if there is an app that can swap all windows between the monitors when I transition between the desks.

Comment: Like how you can have different network settings at different locations?

Comment: I don’t see the connection.

Comment: On network settings you can setup different network settings for different locations - you swap to different location and the other network settings take effect... This sounds like a similar thing - different app window placement based upon some flag.

Comment: I guess so. I’ll take your word for it.